# Find string from slash to a space or a character

Tags: python, regex, findall

I'l like to know how to find a string that is between slach and a bracket or ']' like for example.

```
data = "(AVP:SMTP/xx@xx.xx) R:AVP:SMS.0/+44648474 id:24"
data2 = "(AVP:SMTP/<xxx@xx.xx>) R:AVP:FAX.0/<thisword> id:25"
```

---

si the idea is to get only `xx@xx.xx` and `+44648474` for the first `data` and `xx@xx.xx` and  `thisword`for the `data2`

---

I've tried this regex:

---

```
k = re.findall(r"/(\S+)",data2)
```

---

but it returns `<xxx@xx.xx>)` and `<thisword>`

---

and what i'd like to get is **xx@xx.xx** and **thisword**

Comment: If the substring of your input is `/<xxx@xx.xx>)`, and you want everything between the slash and the bracket, obviously that's going to include the `<` and `>`; if you want to exclude those as well you'll need to do so in your regular expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one works.

```
import re

data = "(AVP:SMTP/xx@xx.xx) R:AVP:SMS.0/+44648474 id:24"
data2 = "(AVP:SMTP/<xxx@xx.xx>) R:AVP:FAX.0/<thisword> id:25"

regex = re.compile(r"/<?([^>\s\)]+)")

print regex.findall(data)
print regex.findall(data2)

>>> 
['xx@xx.xx', '+44648474']
['xxx@xx.xx', 'thisword']
```

---

This regex breakdown:

- `/` : the `/` character.
- `<?` : optionaly a `<` character.
- `(` : start capture group.
- `[^>\s\)]+` : capture anything that is not `>`, `\s` (whitespace), or `)`.
- `)` : close capture group.

Answer (score 1):

You can exclude such delimiters by using [lookaround assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
k = re.findall(r"(?<=/<)[^>]+(?=>)",data2)
```

This would ensure "`/<`" before the match, match then everything that is not "`>`" at least once and succeed when there is a "`>`" after the match.

Comment: thank you but when there's a word between <> it doesn't find the second word.. Inbar Rose's solution works thanks for your help anyway